# c# Web API calling Post at Endpoint not firing when using React Native Fetch Call

Tags: c#, react-native, rest, fetch

API Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace LinkrWebApi.Controllers
{
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [Route("api/values/{country}/{type}")]
    public string Get(string country, string type)
    {






        return "value";
    }

    public class GetResource
    {
        public string countryName { set; get; }
        public string imageLogo { set; get; }
        public string desc { set; get; }
        public string link { set; get; }
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post(string countryName)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
}
```

And my Fetch Call:

```
 fetch('https://localhost:44374/api/values', {
    method: 'post',
    body: "countryName=sc",
    headers: new Headers({
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
                })
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
  //navigation.navigate('FinalResource', { companyName: route.params.companyName, imageLogo: route.params.imageLogo, desc: txtD, link: txtL })

  });
```

But the Post Method in my Web API is not firing, the get works but not the post, can anyone see the mistake?

Comment: You should add `[Http...]` verb attributes to all your actions, and set the routes from that attribute rather than `[Route]` on the action.

Comment: Also, unless you specify a parameter attribute, asp.net will get body content from JSON, not www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: i set the http verbs but what do you mean by route on the action

Comment: `[HttpPost("api/values")]`, `[HttpGet("api/values/{country}/{type}"]`, etc. Use that instead of `[Route]` directly on actions. However, you SHOULD have a `[Route]` attribute on the controller (the class), such as `[Route('api/values"]`, then you don't need to include "api/values" in each of your action route templates.

Comment: i get an error when i add those attributes httppostattribute does not contain a construtor

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. Please read up about routing in asp.net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#http-methods